# FFMPEG Concat failing - System cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I'm a PC. I just reversed a video, and want to combine the original file and the reversed file into one new output.mp4 file

I'm using code copied directly from the ffmpeg wiki

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" <encoding options> output.mkv
```

This is my version:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\uploads\0115171331.mp4 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\uploads\R0115171331.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]"  C:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\output.mp4
```

And when I run it, it just gives me:

> The system cannot find the file specfied.

Again, my other ffmpeg commands worked, and these files (except for output) do exist. I've double checked.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm a PC"?

Comment: @Rightleg I was kind of absent mindledly typing when I did that.  I mean like I use Windows as opposed to doing this on say a Linux server or something

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be that

```
<encoding options>
```

is not a *literal parameter* but user must substitute actual options here.  OP was including it directly causing command to fail.

Comment: ffmpeg runs by itself perfectly fine. I've tried putting the full path. Same thing every time. Sorry, I'm kind of new to ffmpeg

Comment: Some suggestions since this is a tough one to track down remotely.  Try using different values for the filenames.  You tried "the correct path" for C:\xampp\htdocs\reviews\uploads\0115171331.mp4 so try an INVALID filename for this and see what error message you get (is it different?).  Do the same for the next file and the output file.  A little trail-an-error may get ffmpeg to tell you which file it is having a problem finding.  Also try using local, valid files instead of the full path.  So, put some real files in the same directory just in case the full pathname is invalid.

Comment: I tried invalid pathnames, same thing. I put the files in with ffmpeg.exe and   called `ffmpeg -i 0115171331.mp4 -i R0115171331.mp4 \ -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \ -map "[v]" -map "[a]" <encoding options> output.mp4` and that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm thinking it had something to do with maybe the wiki is designed for unix commands or something, and windows isn't handling some of the weird quoted areas properly? I don't have much experience in command line stuff though so I have no idea

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize <encoding options> was meant to be replaced! I think that's what did it

Comment: Yes, the standard convention is for scripts and applications to use <> for parameters that YOU must fill in.  Not always followed but lots of people use that notation.

Comment: This post is not an answer. Please use comments to discuss the topic.